# Run Eclipse on Nexus 7 with Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop

Tags: java, eclipse, nexus-7

I want to develop simply java app (without GUI) on my Nexus 7 (2012) running Ubuntu 13.04 and I have a question.

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Nexus 7 (2012), installed jdk-7u10-ea-fx-8_0_0-embedded-linux-arm-sfp.tar.gz.

After this I downloaded Eclipse Standard 4.3.1, extracted it and tried to run the eclipse executable,but nothing happened.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure: Is there an SWT native library for this setup? Also, zou could check the Eclipse log to see if something gets output there

Comment: As far as I know there is no build for ARM, which version of eclipse did you download? The "standard" 32bit is for x86-architecture.

Comment: Already answered on AskUbuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/358536/run-eclipse-on-nexus-7-with-ubuntu-13-04-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Java is indeed a cross platform language and should work on any platform... but..

Eclipse uses native libraries for it's GUI toolkit ; it's likely you don't have a build of these compiled for ARM. The actual native binaries are encapsulated in the JAR files supplied ; this is why Eclipse bundles come in platform specific flavours, but the Eclipse foundation don't prepare ARM builds.

If you really want Eclipse on Ubuntu on ARM you'll have to build Eclipse, and it's native libraries, for ARM, yourself. I'm not sure as to how practical that is without a certain amount of research.